# How to specify and handle specific errors in Go?

Tags: error-handling, go

I wrote this very basic parser that goes through Reddit JSON and am curious how I can specifically manage an error in Go.

For example I have this "Get" method  for a link:

```
func Get(reddit string) ([]Item, error) {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://reddit.com/r/%s.json", reddit)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, err
    }
    /*
     * Other code here
    */
}
```

How can I handle, say, a 404 error from the StatusCode? I know I can test for the 404 error itself:

```
if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusNotfound {
    //do stuff here
}
```

But is there a way I can directly manage the `resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK` without having to write a bunch of if statements? Is there a way I can use `err` in a switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that [http.Get](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) doesn't return an error for an HTTP return which isn't 200.  The Get did its job successfully even when the server gave it a 404 error. From the docs

> A non-2xx response doesn't cause an error.

Therfore in your code, `err` will be `nil` when you call this which means it will return `err=nil` which probably isn't what you want.

```
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return nil, err
}
```

This should do what you want

```
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("HTTP Error %d: %s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
}
```

Which will return an error for any kind of HTTP error, with a message as to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var err error
    switch err {
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("Is nil")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4VdHW87wCr